# Can't install Zoom on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, zoom-meeting

I'm trying to install Zoom via both the graphical installer and from the terminal. In both cases after downloading the .deb file and running the install command I get the following error (I changed actual IP number for "My IP" in the below terminal output):

```
Err:1 http://mirror.vorboss.net/ubuntu-archive jammy-updates/universe amd64 libegl1-mesa amd64 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
  403  Forbidden [IP: My Ip]
Err:2 http://mirror.vorboss.net/ubuntu-archive jammy-updates/universe amd64 libgl1-mesa-glx amd64 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
  403  Forbidden [IP: My IP]
Err:3 http://mirror.vorboss.net/ubuntu-archive jammy/universe amd64 libxcb-cursor0 amd64 0.1.1-4ubuntu1
  403  Forbidden [IP: My IP]
Get:4 /tmp/zoom_amd64.deb zoom amd64 5.17.5.2543 [185 MB]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.vorboss.net/ubuntu-archive/pool/universe/m/mesa/libegl1-mesa_23.0.4-0ubuntu1%7e22.04.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: My IP]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.vorboss.net/ubuntu-archive/pool/universe/m/mesa/libgl1-mesa-glx_23.0.4-0ubuntu1%7e22.04.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: My IP]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.vorboss.net/ubuntu-archive/pool/universe/x/xcb-util-cursor/libxcb-cursor0_0.1.1-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: My IP]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Did you try to install the _snap_ version?

Answer (score 1):

The mirror you're using "mirror.vorbos.net" looks broken to me. There's missing packages, so it's not a valid mirror of the Ubuntu archive.

Specifically you're trying to install packages from the universe section of the repository which is missing from that mirror.

I'd select a different mirror, and try installing zoom again.